# Tensorflow: difference of get_collection, get_tensor_by_name and get_operation_by_name?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When restoring the model, what's the difference between `get_collection`, `get_tensor_by_name` and `get_operation_by_name`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could `add_collection(name, operation/tensor)` to the graph, and `get_collection(name)` returns a **list** of values in the collection with the given `name`.

`get_tensor_by_name(name)` returns a **tensor** with the given `name`.

`get_operation_by_name(name)` returns a **operation** with the given `name`.