# Tensorflow: difference get_tensor_by_name vs get_operation_by_name?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673771/tensorflow-difference-of-get-collection-get-tensor-by-name-and-get-operation-b) says that one returns an operation while the other returns a tensor. That is pretty obvious from the name and from the documentation. However, suppose I do the following:

```
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, weights), biases, name='logits')
```

I am following the pattern described in [Tensorflow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics). Should I restore it as an operation or as a tensor? I am afraid that if I restore it as a tensor I will only get the last computed values for the logits; nonetheless, the post [here](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/), seems to suggest that there is no difference or that I should just use `get_tensor_by_name`. The idea is to compute the logits for a new set of inputs and then make predictions accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849322/how-to-understand-the-term-tensor-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can use both, `get_operation_by_name()` and `get_tensor_by_name()`. Long answer:

### `tf.Operation`

When you call

```
op = graph.get_operation_by_name('logits')
```

... it returns an instance of type [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation), which is a node in the computational graph, which performs some op on its inputs and produces one or more outputs. In this case, it's a `plus` op.

One can always evaluate an op in a session, and if this op needs some placehoder values to be fed in, the engine will *force* you to provide them. Some ops, e.g. reading a variable, don't have any dependencies and can be executed without placeholders.

In your case, (I assume) `logits` are computed from the input placeholder `x`, so `logits` doesn't have any value without a particular `x`.

### `tf.Tensor`

On the other hand, calling

```
tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('logits:0')
```

... returns an object `tensor`, which has the type [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor):

> Represents one of the outputs of an `Operation`.
>
> A `Tensor` is a symbolic handle to one of the outputs of an `Operation`.
>   It does not hold the values of that operation's output, but instead
>   provides a means of computing those values in a TensorFlow `tf.Session`.

So, in other words, tensor evaluation is the same as operation execution, and all the restrictions described above apply as well.

Why is `Tensor` useful? A `Tensor` can be passed as an input to another `Operation`, thus forming the graph. But in your case, you can assume that both entities mean the same.

Comment: What about the `:0`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Good point, the naming is a bit different too. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36150834/712995